# how to exclude second column from selector

Tags: jquery, selector, filter

my question is how I can change the selector so that it wil exclude
the second column off the hover event

I did try some other variations like nth-child, but no luck yet.
Could there be something wrong with the syntax maybe??

```
$('.row_class td:not(:eq(1))').hover(
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('tr.row_class td:not(:nth-child(2))').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color','red');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

[It works for me](http://jsbin.com/ujiwu).

By the way, class selectors are slow. If you know `.row_class` will only be applied to `<tr>` elements, you should make the selector be `tr.row_class` like in my example. Just a free tip. :)

Comment: $('tr.row_class td:not(:nth-child(2))').hover(

it only selects the first column, and the hover is still attached to the second column

Comment: In the link I put up that is obviously not happening... Try putting your mouse over "Test" and "yay" and they will turn Red. If you put your mouse over "Not" it will stay black. You're doing something else wrong. Do you have the selector wrapped in document.ready?

Comment: I am sorry, I think you are right
I have to change something else, so that it will not respond anymore
to a certain event. Thanks for your input

Answer (score -2):

$('.row_class td:first-child').hover(

Comment: this one only hovers the first cell in the row, I think

Comment: This should work just fine. Especially with the class specified. If that class is on every row and he wants only the first column of that row to have the hover, then this should work great.

Comment: He never said he wanted the first column, he said he _didnt_ want the _second_ column. Presumably he has 3 columns or more and he wants to exclude just the 2nd one. Your example only includes the first one.